# How do you disable security requests from the sender?

Tags: docusignapi

The documents I send through the API recently started requiring security checks (like [this](https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00009045)). How can I disable this feature?

Comment: I had the same issue. Only way to fix it was to call the DocuSign phone support. With the Intermediate API plan, the settings to configure this are not visible in the Admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KBA (Knowledge Based Authentication) check is being performed because either your api request, a template, or the account as a whole is requesting it.

So if you haven't changed your api request, then check the template settings.

I think that the account-level KBA setting is controlled by the DocuSign Customer Service group. Consult them if the template does not include KBA.

Also, try creating a simple signing request from the web tool to a personal or one-time email address (don't use an email that has previously signed from the account). If KBA is used without you setting it, then that's another indication that it is being required at the account level.

Comment: I called customer support and they were able to change the account-level KBA setting.